# cython compiles but no pyd files are generated

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I tried to run a python code, say `myfile.py` (also tried to rename it as `myfile.pyx`) as follows:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={"script_args":["--compiler=mingw32"]},      
    reload_support=True)

import myfile
myfile.mycode()
```

I am using PyCharm. The code seems to have run fine without any error and even gave me correct results on the Python Console within PyCharm.

However no `pyd` (or `pxd`) files were generated. How can I know if my code (`myfile.mycode()`) ran via Cython or via regular Python?

I am using Python 3.4, Cython 0.21.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyximport` generates a temporary `pyd` file that is not in the working directory. You probably want to build a `setup.py` that looks something like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [Extension('myfile',
                         sources=['myfile.pyx'],
                         language='c++',
                        )]
setup(
name = 'myfile',
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

which you can compile using:

```
python setup.py build_ext -i clean
```