# how to compile multiple files in cython

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, distutils

Newbie to Cython. I am using the following code snippet in a file called `setup.py` to compile another file into `Cython` (it was suggested by an SO user to me over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685876/cython-compiles-but-no-pyd-files-are-generated)):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension('func1', ['util/func1_pc.py'],)]

setup(
    name="Set 1 of Functions",
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

I compile it as `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. This compiles my file at `util/func1_pc.py` into `func1.pyd` in the directory of `setup.py`.

Suppose I now have two files: `util/funct1_pc.py` and `util/funct2_pc.py`. Would it be possible for someone to suggest how to modify the above code snippet to generate `func1.pyd` and `func2.pyd` out of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Extension constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=extension#distutils.core.Extension) allows you to specify multiple source files, so changing the `ext_modules` line to this:

```
ext_modules = [Extension('func1', ['util/func1_pc.py', 'util/funct2_pc.py'],)]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: not works `multiple definition of 'PyInit_func1'`

Answer (score 1):

run_cython.pyx - file on same level as setup.py's dirrectory

compilled.pyx - file from dirrectory, layed on same level as setup.py's dir

```sh
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
    'run_cython.pyx',
    './app/compilled.pyx'
)
)
```